# Problema modificar elemento lista Python

Tags: python, lista

```
c1 = Casilla("1", "V", 0, 0)
c2 = Casilla("2", "V", 0, 1)
c3 = Casilla("3", "V", 0, 2)
c4 = Casilla("4", "V", 0, 3)

listaCasillas = []
listaCasillas.append(c1)
listaCasillas.append(c2)
listaCasillas.append(c3)
listaCasillas.append(c4)

cli1 = Cliente("Pepe", 3, 1,        Filas, Columnas)
listaCasillas[3].addCliente(cli1)
```

¿Cómo es posible que si modifico el elmento 3 de la lista, me añada ese cliente en todos los demás objetos? Solo quiero tocar una casilla Soluciones?

Gracias

Comment: quieres que el cambio que haces se refleje en todas las tuplas?

Comment: No no, solo quiero modificar el objeto de la posición 3, concretamente meter un cliente en una lista de ese objeto. Pero me lo mete en todas las listas de las demás casillas

Comment: estas trabajando con clases, podrias poner la clase `Casilla`?

Comment: Si, con clases, la subo en un momento. Pero tiene como parámetro una lista de clientes y luego un método addCliente con un append